# Changing an icon inside a toggle button?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a button that has an icon in it, and I have some jQuery code opening and closing a div.

I have some code that switches the icon from a plus to minus, but the issue is that I have to click directly on the icon for it to work instead being able to click anywhere on the button, and that can be an issue for the minus icon.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<button class="pull-right toggleBtn span1"><i class="icon-plus"></i></button>
```

and my jQuery to switch the icons looks like this:

```
$(".toggleBtn").on('click','.icon-minus, .icon-plus',function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("icon-minus icon-plus");
    });
```

Any help would be awesome!

Comment: Your call to `on()` is filtering by `.icon-minus` and `.icon-plus` which means you are binding the `click` event handler to the `i.icon-plus` rather than its parent `.toggleBtn`.  What you want to do is bind the event handler to `.toggleBtn` and then inside the function toggle the class on the child `i` element using the `.children()` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your JavaScript code to this:

```
$(".toggleBtn").on('click',function(){
    $(this).children('.icon-minus, .icon-plus').toggleClass("icon-minus icon-plus");
});
```

Your current code only listens to the click event on the icon. This code will listen to the click event on the entire button but still change the class only on the icon.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/B4avV/

Comment: Thank you! I spent I don't know how long on this and it turned out to be so simple! It's always the simple things that get me hahaha :)

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$(document).on('click','.toggleBtn',function(){
    $(this).children().toggleClass("icon-minus icon-plus");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(document).on('click','.toggleBtn',function(){
        if ($(this).children().is('.icon-plus')) {
          $(this).children().removeClass('icon-plus');
      }else{
          $(this).children().addClass('icon-plus');
      }
});
```